# Is it possible to hack the laser_assembler to not convert laser scans into point clouds?

Tags: navigation, kinect, turtlebot, ros-hydro, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a turtlebot with a kinect and a hokuyo laser scanner, the goal is to use both scanners /scan topics for gmapping.
Is there a way to hack the laser_assembler to not convert laser scans into point clouds but merge both laser scan data and its tf anyway?

Running with ROS Hydro.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193265/is-it-possible-to-hack-the-laser_assembler-to-not-convert-laser-scans-into-point-clouds?/) by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2014-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No.

Just use the hokuyo for mapping and localization. Having a single sensor with a more consistent view of the world will usually give better results.

(when doing navigation, the navigation stack supports use many sensors for obstacle avoidance)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1